# Undefined reference to library method in Qt C++

Tags: c++, c, qt, linker

I'm trying to use a C library in a C++ program. 
I want to link the library libcoap.a to my program. I've already made a huge program in Qt so it can't be solved by using make instead of qmake.

As a simple example I've made the following code.

connection.h:

```
#include <string>
#include "coap.h"
void sendData(std::string);
```

connection.cpp:

```
#include "connection.h"
#include "coap.h"
coap_uri_t uri;

void sendData(std::string ip){
    coap_split_uri((unsigned char *)ip.c_str(), strlen(ip.c_str()), &uri );
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "connection.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    sendData("[aaaa::c30c:0:0:2]/sen/lt");
    return 0;
}
```

coaptester.pro:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= qt

unix:!macx:!symbian: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../commTest/commTest/libcoap-4.0.1/ -lcoap

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../commTest/commTest/libcoap-4.0.1
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../commTest/commTest/libcoap-4.0.1

unix:!macx:!symbian: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../commTest/commTest/libcoap-4.0.1/libcoap.a

SOURCES += main.cpp \
    connection.cpp
HEADERS += \
    connection.h
```

I always get the same error:

```
undefined reference to `coap_split_uri(unsigned char*, unsigned int, coap_uri_t*)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about surround the #include "coap.h" with extern "C"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use (in connection.h)

```
extern "C" {
    #include "coap.h"
}
```

Besides, it is redundant to include `coap.h` both in `connection.h` and in `connection.cpp` (if in `coap.h` there are no include checks the dimension of your executable will be uselessly greater), so remove it from the .cpp.

Comment: See excellent explanation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041866/in-c-source-what-is-the-effect-of-extern-c)